# Recaptcha is not showing at random times

Tags: react-google-recaptcha

We are using recaptcha, and in our test environment we are using a testing key which we are passing into the component.

The captcha appears and looks like this :

[image]

However sometimes and in some environments the captcha does not appear.

I am unsure why this happens

Looking at the HTML source for when it works correctly, the iFrame is in the source, and an input with a token values can be seen.

[image]

However in the case where no captcha is shown the HTML looks like this :

[image]

An iFrame is appearing in the document source, but there is an empty HTML and BODY tag.

Why would react-google-recaptcha not be showing the checkbox?